# How to do "redirect_to and return" to exit fully or redirect_to immediately?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this as my code:

```
def index
  @monkeys = Monkey.where(owner: current_user)
end

def new
  @monkey = Monkey.new name: 'Monkey 1', alive: true, owner: current_user
end

def create
  @monkey = Monkey.create monkey_params
  # Other fields and save here
end

def edit
  @monkey = Monkey.find_by(id: params[:id], owner: current_user)
  check_on_monkey_first(@monkey)
end

def update
  @monkey = Monkey.find_by(id: params[:id], owner: current_user)
  check_on_monkey_first(@monkey)

  if @monkey.update(monkey_params)
    redirect_to monkeys_path, success: 'Monkey saved'
  end
end

private
def check_on_monkey_first(monkey)
  redirect_to monkeys_path, flash: {info: "Monkey doesn't exist"} and return unless monkey
  redirect_to monkeys_path, flash: {info: "Monkey no longer exist"} and return if !monkey.alive?
end

def monkey_params
  # some_fields_here
end
```

The thing is I think "... and return" only early-exits the `check_on_monkey_first` and then continues on to `update`.

If I am not the owner of the `Monkey`, `find_by` wouldn't get a record and SHOULD do a `redirect_to` because `Monkey` would not exist. But it still continues and breaks code at `if @monkey.update(monkey_params)` because `@monkey` is nil.

How do I do a "redirect_to some_path and return" in Ruby or Rails? How do I stop and do a redirect_to immediately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are likely several solutions, but one might be to return a boolean indicating that you are triggering a redirect. Example:

```
def update
  @monkey = Monkey.find_by(id: params[:id], owner: current_user)

  if check_on_monkey_first(@monkey) and @monkey.update(monkey_params)
    redirect_to monkeys_path, success: 'Monkey saved'
  end
end

private
def check_on_monkey_first(monkey)
  redirect_to monkeys_path, flash: {info: "Monkey doesn't exist"} and return false unless monkey
  redirect_to monkeys_path, flash: {info: "Monkey no longer exist"} and return false if !monkey.alive?
  return true
end
```

A cleaner solution might be to use something like a `before_action` (or `before_filter` for  Rails < v4) for certain actions. It may give you less flexibility as to where you want to perform the `check_on_monkey_first` check, however. For your particular use case, you can try:

```
before_action :check_on_monkey_first, only: [:edit, :update]
```

Then modify your `check_on_monkey_first` to be:

```
def check_on_monkey_first
  @monkey = Monkey.find_by(id: params[:id], owner: current_user)
  redirect_to monkeys_path, flash: {info: "Monkey doesn't exist"} and return unless @monkey
  redirect_to monkeys_path, flash: {info: "Monkey no longer exist"} and return if !@monkey.alive?
end
```

And your `update` action would become:

```
def update
  if @monkey.update(monkey_params)
    redirect_to monkeys_path, success: 'Monkey saved'
  end
end
```

That would let you remove the check in your actions that needed it (edit and update), you don't have to deal with double redirects and it should automatically set the variable for you for those actions.

Comment: I also wanted to do the second one but aside from the CRUD, I have other more actions that would use the same and not all of them had the find_by-and-check at the beginning of the code. So I'm gonna try out the first one.

But with this solutions, does that mean that there is no "redirect_to-and-stop-performing-codes-now"?

Comment: @index Correct, there's currently no built-in action to cause that. The `before_action` is the closest thing to that because it'll detect if a `redirect_to` was called and if so, it won't call the action it is prefacing.

Comment: I see now. I'll keep all this in mind. The first one is the idea that I used now - what I did was to also `return` on the `edit` and `update` methods - `return unless check_on_monkey_first(@monkey)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**before filter**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) that only applies to `edit` and `update`.

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_on_monkey_first, :only => [:edit, :update]

  # other actions ...

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @monkey.update(monkey_params)
      redirect_to monkeys_path, success: 'Monkey saved'
    end
  end

  private
  def check_on_monkey_first
    @monkey = Monkey.find_by(id: params[:id], owner: current_user)
    if @monkey.nil?
      redirect_to monkeys_path, flash: {info: "Monkey doesn't exist"}
    elsif not @monkey.alive?
      redirect_to monkeys_path, flash: {info: "Monkey no longer exist"}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I also wanted to do this but aside from the CRUD, I have other more actions that would use the same and not all of them had the find_by-and-check at the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
private
def check_on_monkey_first(monkey)
  unless monkey
    redirect_to monkeys_path, flash: {info: "Monkey doesn't exist"}
    return 
  else
    unless monkey.alive?
      redirect_to monkeys_path, flash: {info: "Monkey no longer exist"}
      return
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think the `return` here would still only exit `check_on_monkey_first(monkey)`.